# How create Mesh from stl file in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

How can I create a Mesh in Unity from a 
.stl file where I have for each triangle the 3 vertex position (xyz) and the normal vector?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For creating mesh in Unity, first you must define coordinates of vertices and their normals. And according to this vertices, then you need to define UVs and Triangles.

But in a .stl file, you have coordinates of triangles -which you can use to get coordinates of vertices - and Normal vector. If you ask how to do this, it's up to your programming skill.